# Retrofit 2 POST JSON to ThingSpeak Channel

Tags: android, json, post, gson, retrofit2

I am new to Android and developing an app that will send data periodically to a ThingSpeak Channel.

The data will be a list of objects of type Person. I want to send them under JSON format, thus I'm using Retrofit 2 with POST function for this purpose.

Let say I have a channel number 123456 with api_key APIKEY123 and ThingSpeak api: api.thingspeak.com . And my POST function looks like this:

```
POST(URL_STRING)
Call<List<Person>> postData(para1, para2);
```

May I ask what should I put in URL_STRING, para1 and para2? What's the type of encoding tag should I use? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing Retrofit2 service interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595940/implementing-retrofit2-service-interface)

Comment: there are so many apis under thingSpeak, may i know exactly which api you want to call

Comment: Hi, sure. I'm trying to call the api.thingspeak.com with my channel id and api_key. I tried the Postman service to check if the channel is working and I was able to send data to my channel using api_key only and the values for my fields. I'm asking how I would do this behavior on Android. It's even better if I can send the whole list of JSON to ThingSpeak.

Answer (score 0):

have you seen this yet? https://www.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/rest-api.html.

you will need to replace Person, para1, para2 with what you like to do.

For example  - "update a channel" https://www.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/update-a-channel.html

you will replace para1,para2 with api_key and name.

and Person will be replaced with the Channel class containing the json object

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "name": "Updated Channel",
  "description": null,
  "metadata": null,
  "latitude": null,
  "longitude": null,
  "created_at": "2014-03-25T13:12:50-04:00",
  "elevation": null,
  "last_entry_id": null,
  "ranking": 15,
  "username": "hans",
  "tags": [],
  "api_keys":
  [
    {
      "api_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "write_flag": true
    }
  ]
}
```

[Implementing Retrofit2 service interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595940/implementing-retrofit2-service-interface) will give you an idea on how to implement the service interface.

**edit**
the following will have what you need. read up [Implementing Retrofit2 service interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595940/implementing-retrofit2-service-interface) on how to use it.

Syntax for service interface

```
interface InterfaceTS {

    @GET
    Call<Channel> updateChannel(
            @Query("api_key") String key,
            @Query("name") String name);

}
```

Syntax for Channel:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Channel {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private Object description;
    @SerializedName("metadata")
    @Expose
    private Object metadata;
    @SerializedName("latitude")
    @Expose
    private Object latitude;
    @SerializedName("longitude")
    @Expose
    private Object longitude;
    @SerializedName("created_at")
    @Expose
    private String createdAt;
    @SerializedName("elevation")
    @Expose
    private Object elevation;
    @SerializedName("last_entry_id")
    @Expose
    private Object lastEntryId;
    @SerializedName("ranking")
    @Expose
    private Integer ranking;
    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("tags")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> tags = null;
    @SerializedName("api_keys")
    @Expose
    private List<ApiKey> apiKeys = null;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Object getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(Object description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Object getMetadata() {
        return metadata;
    }

    public void setMetadata(Object metadata) {
        this.metadata = metadata;
    }

    public Object getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Object latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Object getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Object longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Object getElevation() {
        return elevation;
    }

    public void setElevation(Object elevation) {
        this.elevation = elevation;
    }

    public Object getLastEntryId() {
        return lastEntryId;
    }

    public void setLastEntryId(Object lastEntryId) {
        this.lastEntryId = lastEntryId;
    }

    public Integer getRanking() {
        return ranking;
    }

    public void setRanking(Integer ranking) {
        this.ranking = ranking;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public List<Object> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(List<Object> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    public List<ApiKey> getApiKeys() {
        return apiKeys;
    }

    public void setApiKeys(List<ApiKey> apiKeys) {
        this.apiKeys = apiKeys;
    }

}
```

Syntax for API Key

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ApiKey {

    @SerializedName("api_key")
    @Expose
    private String apiKey;
    @SerializedName("write_flag")
    @Expose
    private Boolean writeFlag;

    public String getApiKey() {
        return apiKey;
    }

    public void setApiKey(String apiKey) {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }

    public Boolean getWriteFlag() {
        return writeFlag;
    }

    public void setWriteFlag(Boolean writeFlag) {
        this.writeFlag = writeFlag;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried following their documentation but it does not work, that's why I'm asking. Could you please give a concrete syntax example based on my details above? I understand the flow but syntax is the thing I'm asking here. Thanks a lot.